# Prevent sed from printing empty stuff

Tags: sed

```
sed -e 's/\([A-Za-z]*\)\( \)\([A-Za-z]*\)\(:\?\)\([A-Za-z]*\)\?\( \)\?\(.*\)\?/[\1][\2][\3][\4][\5][\6][\7]/'
```

will decorate

```
class VoxelbuilderAdda:public VoxelBuilder
```

So it looks like

```
[class][ ][VoxelbuilderAdda][:][public][ ][VoxelBuilder]
```

If I instead have

```
class VoxelBuilder
```

The output is

```
[class][ ][VoxelBuilder][][][][]
```

Is it possible to stop it from printing the empty brackets?

**The goal** is to print all identifiers with like (square brackets are my simple placeholders but I should have excluded them for the keywords)

```
\textclassname{VoxelBuilder}
```

and leave keywords (class, struct, public, ...) and separators like ':' as is.

**Obviously an inverted pattern for keywords+separator is more beneficial, but I could not figure it out**. I actually want

Replace sequence X with \textclassname{X} only if X is not one of

- `class`
- `struct`
- `union`
- `public`
- `private`
- `protected`
- `virtual`
- `:`
- `,`
- `<`
- `>`
- 

I have stripped out curly braces and semicolon in an earlier step. The goal would be

```
class \textclassname{VoxelbuilderAdda}:public \textclassname{VoxelBuilder}
```

With no inheritance

```
class \textclassname{VoxelbuilderAdda}
```

If I had the not operator available, It would not only cover those I have, but any weird multiple inheritance as well.

Comment: Question: Is your sequence like `class, public, …` always begin from start of line or other puctuation symbol like `:, >, <, …`?

Comment: @Costas The compound type (class,struct,union) is always at the beginning of line. For the rest, assume it is correct C++ syntax.

Comment: `sed 's/ \(\w*\)/ \\textclassname{\1}/g'`

Comment: @Costas: Almost, but `struct \textclassname{Twins}:public \textclassname{std}::pair<T,T>` is still wrong. Should have been`struct \textclassname{Twins}:public \textclassname{std}::\textclassname{pair}<\textclassname{T},\textclassname{T}>`

Comment: `sed 's/\(::\|[<, ]\)\(\w\+\)/\1\\textclassname{\2}/g'`

Comment: @Costas You may post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such kind of conversion is better to use special parse-tools but if you'd like to operate file like a text try:

```
sed 's/\(::\|[<, ]\)\(\w\+\)/\1\\textclassname{\2}/g' filename
```

or use -r option to avoid extra-escaping:

```
sed -r 's/(::|[<, ])(\w+)/\1\\textclassname{\2}/g' filename
```

Comment: Would it be possible to snap the class name (the word after the first white-space) as a sub-expression (so I can generate a label for it)

Answer (score 1):

so you have to treat spaces, words and colons separately:

```
sed -e 's/[A-Za-z]\{1,\}/[&]/g' -e 's/:/[&]/g' -e 's/ /[&]/g'
```

this will replace a) one or more `\{1,\}` occurences of any letter with the pattern `&` surrounded by square brackets, b and c) replace a single colon (space) by itself surrounded by square brackets

```
echo class VoxelbuilderAdda:public VoxelBuilder | sed -e 's/[A-Za-z]\{1,\}/[&]/g' -e 's/:/[&]/g' -e 's/ /[&]/g'
[class][ ][VoxelbuilderAdda][:][public][ ][VoxelBuilder]
```

Comment: This is not really correct, I need the _keywords_ "class", "struct", and "public" treated separately. They shall have no additional markup.

Comment: please update your question with the desired output.

Comment: `s/\w*\|:\| /[&]/g` is enough for GNU sed

Comment: I get that `\|` mean "OR", but how to understand the `\w*`? What would be the matches? Is it "greedy word", are numbers excluded, what are the separators?

Comment: @Fiximan From `man grep`: "…The symbol `\w` is a  synonym  for  `[_[:alnum:]]`…"